# Static Factory Methods vs Constructors

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

This questions derailed in the comment section and is more related to the advatanges of Static Factory Methods vs Constructors

Take the following as an example

```
export class User extends Model<UserProps> {

  // Suggested Method (With no constructor)
  static buildUser(attrs: UserProps) : User {
    return new User(new Attributes(attrs), new Eventing(), new ApiSync(rootUrl));
  }

  // why not do it like this instead? No need to call User.buildUser()
  constructor(attrs: UserProps) {
    super(new Attributes(attrs), new Eventing(), new ApiSync(rootUrl));
  }
}
```

I understand that only implementing the buildUser method would implicitally call the constructor with super and the args if the constructor is never defined.

However is there some features that buildUser will provide that a direct super call within the constructor wouldnt?

Just seems like "extra" code to create a user.

```
let user = User.buildUser(some attr)
```

vs

```
let user = new User(some attr);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a `static` method is. The first case would just be: `let user = User.buildUser(some attr)`.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake there. Even then, you would be calling new User.buildUser(some attr) vs new User(some attr). Seems more intuative to just call new User(someattr)

Comment: No, not using `new` in the first case. The pattern is called a "static factory method". Googling for that should yield some reference articles.

Comment: I'll take a look thanks. Is this generally the prefered method?

Comment: I don't know about generally. I use it often in cases where I don't want to pollute my constructor with argument checking and things like that.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve, and your coding style I believe. It's generally usefull and used in the case you have multiple way to construct an element, and you do not want to have a biiiig constructor doing all type check etc... for each case, or just for lisibility. like this exemple.

https://stackify.com/static-factory-methods/

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks a lot for the responses all of you.

Comment: It was a suggested edits by a user. The discussion is more related to Design Patterns in OOP than the TypeScript syntax itself

Comment: Ah. Well, you don't have to approve edits you think are clearly wrong/bad/irrelevant, and can roll them back if others approve them (especially on your own question) :-)

Comment: I was thinking it could improve the answer rate as the question is more about OOP and less about the language.

Answer (score 1):

*note: This is an OOP question, not so much a typescript one. I will provide my examples in Java since that is my comfort area. It's all applicable and examples should be simple enough for any programmer to grasp.*

## Naming

Take this example:

```
   final Duration a = new Duration (1); // <-- 1 hour
   final Duration a = new Duration (0, 1); // <-- 1 minute
   final Duration a = new Duration (0, 0, 1); // <-- 1 second
   final Duration a = new Duration (0, 0, 0, 1); // <-- 1 millisecond

   final Duration a = Duration.ofHours(1); // <-- 1 hour
   final Duration a = Duration.ofMinutes(1); // <-- 1 minute
   final Duration a = Duration.ofSeconds(1); // <-- 1 second
   final Duration a = Duration.ofMillis(1); // <-- 1 millisecond
```

First advantage of static factory methods: *They have names*

## Caching

Take this example:

```
private static final Map <Integer, Duration> CACHE = Maps.newHashMap();

public static Duration ofHours(final int value) {
        return Duration.CACHE.computeIfAbsent(
            value, v -> new Duration(v);
        );
    }
}
```

Second advantage of static factory methods: *They can cache*

## Subtyping

Take this example:

```
public static Duration ofHours(final int value) {

    if(value < 24)
        return new Duration(value, 0, 0, 0);
    else
        return new MultiDayDuration(...);
}

public static class MultiDayDuration extends Duration {
   ...
}
```

Third advantage of static factory methods: *They can subtype*

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @Crocsx provides examples with advantages of Static Factories vs Constructor only. https://stackify.com/static-factory-methods/